# Permute rows in "slices" of 3d array to match each other

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, cluster-analysis

I have a series of 2d arrays where the rows are points in some space. Many similar points occur across all arrays but in different row order. **I want to sort the rows so they have the most similar order.** Also the points are too different for clustering with K-means or DBSCAN. The problem can also be cast like this. If I stack the arrays into a 3d array, how do I permute the rows to minimize the average standard deviation (SD) along the 2nd axis? **What's a good sorting algorithm for this problem?**

I've tried the following approaches.

1. Create a set of reference 2d array and sort rows in each array to minimize mean euclidean distances to the reference 2d array. *This I am afraid gives biased results.*
2. Sort rows in arrays pairwise, then pairs of pair-medians, then pairs of that, etc... This doesn't really work and I'm not sure why.

A third approach could be just brute force optimization but I try to avoid that since I have multiple sets of arrays to perform the procedure on.

This is my code for the 2nd approach (Python):

```
def reorder_to(A, B):
    """Reorder rows in A to best match rows in B.

    Input
    -----
    A : N x M numpy.array
    B : N x M numpy.array

    Output
    ------
    perm_order : permutation order
    """

    if A.shape != B.shape:
        print "A and B must have the same shape"
        return None

    N = A.shape[0]

    # Create a distance matrix of distance between rows in A and B
    distance_matrix = np.ones((N, N))*np.inf
    for i, a in enumerate(A):
        for ii, b in enumerate(B):
            ba = (b-a)
            distance_matrix[i, ii] = np.sqrt(np.dot(ba, ba))

    # Choose permutation order by smallest distances first
    perm_order = [[] for _ in range(N)]
    for _ in range(N):
        ind = np.argmin(distance_matrix)
        i, ii = ind/N, ind%N
        perm_order[ii] = i
        distance_matrix[i, :] = np.inf
        distance_matrix[:, ii] = np.inf

    return perm_order


def permute_tensor_rows(A):
    """Permute 1d rows in 3d array along the 0th axis to minimize average SD along 2nd axis.

    Input
    -----
    A : numpy.3darray
        Each "slice" in the 2nd direction is an independent array whose rows can be permuted
        to decrease the average SD in the 2nd direction.

    Output
    ------
    A : numpy.3darray
        A with sorted rows in each "slice".
    """
    step = 2
    while step <= A.shape[2]:
        for k in range(0, A.shape[2], step):

            # If last, reorder to previous
            if k + step > A.shape[2]:
                A_kk = A[:, :, k:(k+step)]
                kk_order = reorder_to(np.median(A_kk, axis=2), np.median(A_k, axis=2))
                A[:, :, k:(k+step)] = A[kk_order, :, k:(k+step)]
                continue

            k_0, k_1 = k, k+step/2
            kk_0, kk_1 = k+step/2, k+step

            A_k = A[:, :, k_0:k_1]
            A_kk = A[:, :, kk_0:kk_1]

            order = reorder_to(np.median(A_k, axis=2), np.median(A_kk, axis=2))
            A[:, :, k_0:k_1] = A[order, :, k_0:k_1]

        print "Step:", step, "\t ... Average SD:", np.mean(np.std(A, axis=2))
        step *= 2

    return A
```

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem, but I don't quite understand it from your current explanation.

Comment: Total variance rather than average standard deviation might be a better metric

Comment: 'Doesn't really work'  What is that supposed to mean?  Actual errors in the code?  Runs but you don't like the result?  How do we know if code is right?

Comment: I suppose I can explain what my approach is, but it's easier read from the code. Anyway the function permutes the rows in each slice alright but it doesn't decrease the average SD in the 2nd direction. And I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I should have looked at your code sample; that was very informative.

Seems like this here gives an out-of-the-box solution to your problem:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html#scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment

Only really feasible for a few 100 points at most though, in my experience.

Comment: This looks like job assignment. How do you suggest I recast the problem to solve it with this approach?